# Email recruiter to thank them

Tags: recruitment, job-offer

I received two job offers through two different headhunters. The one I turned down was quite disappointed, she genuinely felt hers was the better role for me (which it might be - it was literally a coin toss deciding between the two offers), she spent a lot of time understanding my job search criteria. I'm questioning whether I made the right choice! I want to send her an email, thanking her for all the effort but it was a difficult choice for me, hope to stay in contact in future - maybe take her out for a quick coffee to thank her, and perhaps if she could put in a few good words to the company for me and thank them for the opportunity - just in case my current role doesn't work out in a few months time and they still haven't found someone suitable, I would definitely be interested in the position. How should I write this email - she's probably still furious that she didn't get her commission!

Answer (score 3):

I doubt she's furious and you're certainly not the first one to turn down an offer for a better one.

Just word the email casually and don't sweat it.

As for taking her out to coffee, remember that to someone in sales, time is money and she may not have any for someone who currently isn't in her pipeline.

I'm certain she'll want to keep your contact information because just because you aren't a commission today doesn't mean that you (or someone you refer) won't be in the future.

Regarding being interested in that position in the future, just assume that it's already gone to the next candidate. If it's still open when you contact her looking for more work, she'll let you know.